# insertar datos en tabla

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

buend día.

Tengo un login donde meto el correo y la pass. Y quiero que al momento de poner el user y la pass, me llene en otra tabla que tengo el Id del usuario que logeo, Nombre y Fecha del momento del logeo.

```
var IdUser = db.AccesoLogin.Where(x => x.Id == us.Id);
var Nombre = db.AccesoLogin.Where(x => x.Nombre == us.NameIdentifier);
var Fecha = db.AccesoLogin.Where(x => x.Fecha == DateTime.Now);
```

Estas 3 variables son las que uso para obtener los datos de la persona que inicia sesión.

Y no se me ocurre alguna forma de poder insertar los datos a la tabla que quiero.

Esta es la función que tengo.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No Valid Model");
                return View(model);
            }

            var us = UserManager.FindByEmail(model.Email);
            if (us != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Usuario Encontrado");
                if (!us.Enabled)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Usuario Inactivo");
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Usuario Inactivo.");
                    return View(model);
                }
            }



            AccesoLogin Al = new AccesoLogin();

            var IdUser = db.AccesoLogin.Where(x => x.Id == us.Id);
            var Nombre = db.AccesoLogin.Where(x => x.Nombre == us.NameIdentifier);
            var Fecha = db.AccesoLogin.Where(x => x.Fecha == DateTime.Now);
            

            // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
            // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
            var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
            switch (result)
            {
                case SignInStatus.Success:
                    Console.WriteLine("SignInStatus.Success");
                    return RedirectToLocal("~/Home/Index/");
                case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                    Console.WriteLine("Lockout");
                    return View("Lockout");
                case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                    return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
                case SignInStatus.Failure:
                default:
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Usuario y/o contraseña incorrectos.");
                    return View(model);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Tengo 3 preguntas para ti: 1. ¿Cuál es el problema? 2. ¿Cómo haces debugging? 3. ¿Has verificado que los datos que quieres en esas 3 variables sean los que estás esperando?

Comment: El problema que tengo es que no se me ocurre como insertar esos datos que tengo en las variables (Que ya verifique que si obtiene los datos en momento de logear) a otra que tengo.  He buscado con SqlConnection pero no es lo mejor

Comment: Pues es simple, extiende el método `PasswordSignInAsync`, lecturas recomendadas: https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/extending-the-asp-net-core-identity-signinmanager +https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.identitybuilderextensions.addsigninmanager

Comment: Gracias, me sirvio

Comment: En la parte inferior donde dice "Tu Respuesta", incluye lo que hiciste para resolver tu caso, serás el héroe de más personas que tengan el mismo escenario. Recuerda aceptar la respuesta a las 24 horas de haber publicado, ayudarás a mantener la buena salud del sitio (% de preguntas resueltas). Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tan solo cree el objeto a la DB que quiero y desde el objeto apunte a las variable del usuario que iniciaba sesión.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No Valid Model");
                return View(model);
            }

            var us = UserManager.FindByEmail(model.Email);
            if (us != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Usuario Encontrado");
                if (!us.Enabled)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Usuario Inactivo");
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Usuario Inactivo.");
                    return View(model);
                }
            }



            AccesoLogin accesoLogin = new AccesoLogin();

            accesoLogin.UserId = us.Id;
            accesoLogin.Nombre = us.NameIdentifier;
            accesoLogin.Fecha = DateTime.Now;

            db.AccesoLogin.Add(accesoLogin);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            

            // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
            // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
            var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
            switch (result)
            {
                case SignInStatus.Success:
                    Console.WriteLine("SignInStatus.Success");
                    return RedirectToLocal("~/Home/Index/");
                case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                    Console.WriteLine("Lockout");
                    return View("Lockout");
                case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                    return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
                case SignInStatus.Failure:
                default:
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Usuario y/o contraseña incorrectos.");
                    return View(model);
            }
        }
```